# ¿Es posible disparar un evento cuando un item de un ListViewCollection cambia?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm

estoy trabajando hace poco en WPF, y me ha surgido una duda.

Tengo dos ViewModel,

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Ejemplo { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }      
}

public class Bar
{
    private ObservableCollection<Foo> mFooList;
    public ListCollectionView FooList { get; set; }
    public Bar()
    {
        //Lleno la lista observable 
        FooList = new ListCollectionView(mFooList);   
    }
}
```

Hasta este punto, todo funciona correcto, ya que `FooList` es `Filtrable`  **y** editable a su vez.

El ViewModel `Bar` se representaría visualmente con un `DataGrid` en el cual aparecerá el `string Ejemplo` en una columna, y en otra un `CheckBox` que permita la posibilidad de chequear la fila correspondiente.

Lo manejo de la siguiente manera:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FooList}"
    CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:Foo}"
>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ejemplo" Binding="{Binding Path=Ejemplo}" IsReadOnly="True"/>                
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Debe exportarse?" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

El asunto, es que necesito detectar cuando un `CheckBox` es tildado, o destildado, pero no estoy logrando detectarlo con el ViewModel mediante `INotifyPropertyChanged` ni bindear un `Command` en la propiedad `Checked` del `CheckBox`

¿Cómo debo notificar a la vista para poder reaccionar a un cambio en la columna de los `CheckBox`?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo con un `Command`, para poder bindearlo tuve que usar `RelativeSource` y `AncestorType` para llegar a la ventana y así poder ubicar el `Command` que necesitaba usar.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=DataContext.Check}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

De esta manera, se ejecuta el `ICommand` que pertenece al ViewModel `Bar` llamado `Check`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no haria falta utilizar un ICommand, si estableces Mode=TwoWay en la propiedad Binding.

Este enlace aunque antiguo, puede resolverte tu duda.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-binding-mode-in-wpf/

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero lamentablemente el método que planteas no funciona, debido a que `ListViewCollection` no implementa `INotifyPropertyChanged`